# Unable to verify a special character string in Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress, contains

I have to verify a special character string on a webpage on different elements using Cypress.

Special character string is : `T!@$^()-_+, &_-=tt.Ø {y}[a] £ fi`

Whenever I try to verify the string I get below assertion error in Cypress:

`AssertionError Timed out retrying after 4000ms: Expected to find content: 'T!@$^()-+, &-=tt.Ø {y}[a] £ fi' within the element: <label> but never did.`

Below is the screenshot:
[image]

Below is the code block:

```
    cy.visit('public/special-character.html')
    
    cy.get('label').contains('T!@$^()-_+, &_-=tt.Ø {y}[a] £ fi');
    cy.get('p').contains('T!@$^()-_+, &_-=tt.Ø {y}[a] £ fi');
   
  })
```

and also attached a sample HTML page:

```html
<html><head>
<title>Special Character String</title>

<body>
<h3> Below is the special charcter string needs to be verified using Cypress</h3>
<label>T!@$^()-_+, &_-=tt.Ø {y}[a] £ fi</label>
<p>T!@$^()-_+, &_-=tt.Ø {y}[a] £ fi</p>
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 9):

This looks like a bug.

The part of the text `=tt.Ø {y}[a]` is causing it to fail. Looks like it's evaluating to a function declaration.

If you try that part of the text in isolation, it also fails

```js
cy.get('label').contains('=tt.Ø {y}[a]')  // fails
```

but one char less either end passes

```js
cy.get('label')
  .contains('=tt.Ø {y}[a')
  .should('have.prop', 'tagName', 'LABEL')  // passes

cy.get('label')
  .contains('tt.Ø {y}[a]')
  .should('have.prop', 'tagName', 'LABEL')  // passes
```

Splitting the string and using `.contains()` on each section will also pass

```js
const specChars = 'T!@$^()-_+, &_-=tt.Ø {y}[a] £ fi'

const splitChar = 'Ø'   
const [first, second] = specChars.split(splitChar) 
cy.get('label')
  .contains(first)
  .contains(splitChar)
  .contains(second)
  .should('have.prop', 'tagName', 'LABEL')
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to test?

- If you want to get the element, `get` already fetches it. So no need for it. Otherwise, if you want to retrieve `<label>`, you can do your `cy.contains` at the top

```
cy.contains('T!@$^()-_+, &_-=tt.Ø {y}[a] £ fi').should('exist'); // return <label>
```

- If you want to assert that the text contains the desired text, you can try the following:

```
cy.get('label').should('have.text','T!@$^()-_+, &_-=tt.Ø {y}[a] £ fi');
```